# Using Sybase ASE 12.5.4 with jTDS drivers with JRuby

Tags: jdbc, jruby, sap-ase, jtds, activerecord-jdbc

**Problem**

I am trying to build a small ruby script - which will be run using jruby once a day - to connect to a Sybase ASE 12.5.4 database and perform a complex query.

Ultimately I intend to do some processing on the data and insert the new data in a MySQL table for use within a rails application.

**Environment**

- jruby v1.4.0
- java v1.6.0_15
- on Ubuntu Karmic

**JRuby Installed Gems**

- activerecord-jdbc-adapter (0.9.1)
- activerecord-2.3.4

**Jruby Lib Directory**

- jtds-1.2.5

**Query**

```
SET rowcount 10 
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
```

**Code Snippet**

```
require 'java'
require 'jtds-1.2.5.jar'
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

config = {
    :username => 'railstest',
    :password => 'railstest',
    :adapter  => 'jdbc',
    :dialect  => 'sybase',
    :host     => 'localhost',
    :database => 'railstest',
    :port     => '5000',
    :driver   => 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver',
    :url      => 'jdbc:jtds:sybase://localhost:5000/railstest'
}
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config).connection.execute(-- QUERY --)
```

I can confirm this connects to the DB. Although I am having issues just selecting 10 rows from a database table.

**Produces**

For **execute** method:

```
/usr/local/bin/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `log': ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: The executeUpdate method must not return a result set.: SET rowcount 10 SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE  (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
        from /usr/local/bin/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-0.9.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:559:in `execute'
        from db-test.rb:21
```

For **select_rows** method:

```
/usr/local/bin/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `log': ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: The executeUpdate method must not return a result set.: SET rowcount 10 SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
        from /usr/local/bin/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-0.9.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:559:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/bin/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-0.9.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:629:in `select'
        from /usr/local/bin/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-0.9.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter.rb:550:in `select_rows'
        from db-test.rb:21
```

The error states that I should not return a results set but it doesn't matter which method I use, execute, select_rows etc nothing works.

One more thing regarding queries. My original query is rather complex, I decalre variables, drop temporary tables and create temporary tables as well as populate and select from them. Using Squirrel SQL I can execute once and gain a result. Using DBI I was unable to do this in one execution, does anyone know if I can just execute the whole thing once or will I have to split it up?

Would anyone be able to give me any assistance please? Am I using jTDS properly? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `SET rowcount 10` part of the query you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been using the Sybase drivers for sometime as suggested by @lollipopman which was helpful in getting going but as I built more complex queries I kept running into issues so I tried to revisit the original problem and with an hour or so I go it working.

Find the open source jTDS drivers [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

```
require java
require jtds-1.2.5.jar
require rubygems
require dbi

dbh = DBI.connect('dbi:Jdbc:jtds:sybase://<host>:<port>/<db>', <username>, <password>, {'driver' => 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'} )
```

And that is all that is needed to connect to your Sybase Database with JRuby and DBI

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

not entirely relevant, but this is what is required when using jruby, sybase jdbc and dbi:

```
require 'java'
require './jars/jTDS3.jar'
require './jars/jconn3.jar'
require "rubygems"
require "dbi"

dbh = DBI.connect('dbi:Jdbc:sybase:Tds:foobar:2460/testdb', 'sa', 'password',
  {'driver' => 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'} )
```

Comment: I tried this and I can connect to my Database - thanks lollipopman

For anyone reading this you need to download the drivers from the Sybase website: http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/softwaredeveloperkit/jconnect

Register and download the archive - you need jTDS3.jar and jconn3.jar which can be found in the archive in the classes folder.

I still would prefer to use ActiveRecord and will pursue how to get this resolved.

@lollipopman why DBI drivers? Does this give you better performance?

Comment: Glad to here you got it working, I am not using ruby on rails so DBI is sufficient for my scripting needs.

Comment: @lollipopman: Although i use rails, this is for a cron process which will run once a day and populate a table which will be used by the rails app. I just wanted to use active record within the ruby script

As I said I have something working now sow will continue with this path for now

Comment: @lollipopman: have you had any issues getting column names using DBI drivers?

Comment: I posted this issue here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530329/jrruby-sybase-jdbc-and-dbi-fetching-column-name-with-the-as-clause-issue

Answer (score 0):

Note :
you are saying "set rowcount" and "select". These are two different statements - they both get results, even if it's "0 rows" ... So you ARE getting a resultset.
Try to execute those separately.

Comment: Agreed this is part of the issue and have resolved. Can I ask your advice on which method to use to return a result set. I keep getting a FIXNUM object ie. a number of results. This is all very experimental for me